# Is it right to use a float numbers instead of text in design

Tags: mobile, design, text, numbers

We have a design that indicate the user about the measurement of food ingredients

For example:

- 1.5 cup
- 0.5 cup

Is it right to use it as above or replace it with

- 1 cup and half
- A half of cup

Comment: In your examples the first (decimal) option is clearer. However, I think part of your problem with the second option is the awkward grammar. It should be `"One and a half cups of..."` and `"Half a cup of..."`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to see it as a **fraction**, e.g. 1 1/2 cups or as a **decimal number** (1.5 cup, your first proposal).

Chefkoch (a German website about cooking) uses fractions for whole pieces and decimal numbers for weights or volumes.

[image: chefkoch ui]

Answer (score 0):

This will partly depend how you expect your recipes to be used. Are we talking about a recipe book? An app? A smart speaker skill?

In general I would probably avoid decimals -- when you're in the heat of the kitchen, the decimal point/period/comma is relatively easy to miss (especially if it has a speck of flour or a splash of sauce covering it up!), which could easily ruin your recipe. For this reason, it's fairly uncommon to see decimals in recipe books, at least the ones I have.

On the other hand, numbers are still easier to read at a glance than wordy sentences, so I kind of agree with @Nash that fractions might be the best option. Even if the small numerator/denominator are harder to read from a distance, it's immediately obvious at a glance that the required measurement is "one whole number plus a bit extra".

Comment: Although I agree it's a fair point to make, I can't help but laugh at the thought of somebody accidentally using 15 cups of flour instead of 1.5 cups. Seriously, you probably shouldn't be cooking if you make that mistake :D